# Exclude records if right table matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table:

Table **A**:

```
+--+----+
|id|name|
+--+----+
|0 |foo |
|1 |bar |
|2 |baz |
+-------+
```

Table **B**:

```
+--+----+
|A |cond|
+--+----+
|0 |X   |
|1 |Y   |
+-------+
```

Where B.A column is A.id value.

I want to select all row from **A** where have no match in **B** table when B.cond = 'X'.

So, result should be:

- bar
- baz

How to write this SQL request with join (or similar performance method) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  A.*
FROM
  A
LEFT JOIN
  B
  ON A.id = B.A
  AND B.cond = 'X'
WHERE
  B.A IS NULL
```

This query joins the tables based on the conditions you specified, and then only selects the rows where there's no match in table `B`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM B
    WHERE b.A = a.id AND b.cond = 'X'
)
```

However, i always forget that MySql is the only(?) rdbms which has problems to optimize an `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`. So it's slightly more efficient to use a `LEFT JOIN` approach.

http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

In MS SQL-Server it's better to use the `NOT EXISTS`.

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: about performance question, NOT EXIST is less, better or equal with JOIN ?

Comment: @bux Why not suck it and see?

Comment: @bux You might find this article interesting: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ although it might be slightly out of date.

Comment: @Strawberry Because make strict comparaison (without caches, etc) is not quick.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the links, Tim! It's always good to have some references.

Comment: Quassnoi's article (like all his articles) is superb on this - but I think the conclusions are a little out of date. While I can't remotely match the performance of his machine, I can confirm that `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` run in approximately half the time compared with `LEFT JOIN... WHERE... IS NULL`. As an old-fashioned SQL purist, I find this result a little depressing.

Comment: @Strawberry: do the compare columns have an index?

Comment: Yes - exactly as per Quassnoi's example. Oh - and version 5.5.16 in this instance

Comment: @Strawberry: i'm suprised and a little bit disappointed if EXISTS is such a mess on MySql. I'm on SQL-Server most of the time. However, if the tables aren't large i would use the most readable approach. (NOT) `EXISTS` wins in this respect imo.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the proposed solutions, using `not in` would work too:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT A FROM B WHERE COND = 'X')
```

It should perform on par with a `left join` and is a bit more compact.

Comment: I haven't considered this approach. Thanks for sharing!