# MySQL query to list users not in another table

Tags: mysql

```
 id   username
| 1 | john
| 2 | mike
| 3 | Tim
| 4 | Jake
| 5 | Sam

follower_id    followed_id
|      1     |       3
|      1     |       4
```

John is following Tim and Jake. How would I return a list of the users John is ***not*** following?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude records if right table matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239077/exclude-records-if-right-table-matches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume the table names as `user` and `user_to_follower`.

- Start with `user` table and do a `LEFT JOIN` to the other table. Since you want to consider all the users which are not following 'John', you need to consider `user` table first.
- Note that in the LEFT JOIN, variable 'JOHN' is set by `f.follower_id = 1` in the `ON` clause.
- Now, just filter out those users where **follower_id** `is null`.
- **This Join based solution is more efficient than using a Subquery.**

Try the following query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username 
FROM user AS u 
LEFT JOIN user_to_follower AS f ON f.followed_id = u.id 
                                   AND f.follower_id = 1 
WHERE f.follower_id IS NULL
```

Comment: You're the man! Thank you.

Comment: @onosendi happy to help :)

Comment: If I want to expand my question by adding a table, should I edit the current question or create a new one?

Comment: @onosendi please create a new one. It can be answered there

Answer (score 1):

Try a sub-query, something like this:

```
SELECT id, username
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT followed_id FROM follows WHERE follower_id = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically LEFT JOIN where the joined table is NULL:

```
SELECT
u.*
FROM
 users u
LEFT JOIN follows f ON f.followed_id = u.id AND f.follower_id = 1
WHERE

 AND f.follower_id IS NULL
```